# equivalent to soft assertion for locators in playwright

Tags: testing, e2e-testing, playwright

I have a test that I want to continue even if a locator call fails. I know about soft assertions, and they work as expected for my use case, but is there an equivalent for `page.locator().someMethod()`?

```js
// test will continue executing past this line if #some-selector doesn't contain 'some text'
expect.soft(page.locator('#some-selector')).toHaveText('some text')

// this button may not exist, but I still want to try clicking it
await page.locator('#may-not-exist').click()

// how can I run this if the line above it fails?
await page.locator('#will-exist').click()
```

I want the last line of the test to run regardless if *either* expect.soft fails **or** if a page.locator invocation fails.

Is there something like `page.locator.soft()` in Playwright API? I've [looked through all the methods](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for) and don't see anything like it.

Answer (score 2):

Test test is stopped here:

```js
await page.locator('#may-not-exist').click() 
// not at an assertion line
```

Because Playwright won't be able to interact with an element that doesn't exist.

If you must click on `#will-exist` you can write this:

```js
expect.soft(page.locator('#some-selector')).toHaveText('some text');

const mayNotExist = await page.locator('#may-not-exist');
// checks if locator is visible on DOM
if (mayNotExist.isVisible()) 
{  
  await mayNotExist.click();
}

await page.locator('#will-exist').click(); // clicks on locator anyway!
```

Comment: unfortunately test execution does not continue past the if statement, bc the page is closed after the locator failure—there is no `page` post failure for `page.locator('#will-exist')` to locate

Comment: I've written selectors conditionally, as you stated. They may be different.

Comment: right, but may-not-exist definitely doesn't exist and still if it fails it won't continue—i was actually able to do something similar to the desired outcome by using `const someButton = await page.$("text='this wont exist'")` and then passing that to an if statement... so, similar to what you had, just without the await page.locator, thanks!

Comment: Hmm, that's weird! If the selector doesn't match it should return undefined or false not break the test unless action is called upon the selector.

Comment: Can you tell me what error is displayed on the terminal?

Comment: right yeah I removed the click from the second line as u had first had it and only called click if found, yet the error was still `locator.click: Target page, context or browser has been closed` (on code that comes after that assignment